# How to bind data to ListBox.ItemSource using MVVM pattern

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I'm developer of WP7 application.
Does anyone know the idea that how to bind data to ListBox.ItemSource in a ViewModel class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding ViewModelPropertyName}" />
```

`ViewModelPropertyName` should return an `IList` or better.
If you want to show changes to the collection, it should return an `INotifyCollectionChanged`, such as `ObservableCollection<T>`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding ViewModelPropertyName}" />
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding PropertyNameWithinObject} />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. I found a sample that you wrote. I'll try it. Also please let me know good sample if you know.

Answer (score 0):

on the same above example, you need to define the binding name "ViewModelPropertyname" in class

Example: class name as "Model"

```
        int _PropertyNameWithinObject;
        public int PropertyNameWithinObject
        {
            get
            {
                return PropertyNameWithinObject;
            }
            set
            {
                PropertyNameWithinObject= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PropertyNameWithinObject");
            }
        }
```

Include the following class on the class "Model"

```
public class ViewModelBaseEx : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then define the collection in another class in neat named as "ViewModel"

```
        ObservableCollection<Model> _ViewModelPropertyName= new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        public ObservableCollection<Model> ViewModelPropertyName
        {
            get
            {
                return _ViewModelPropertyName;
            }
            set
            {
                _ViewModelPropertyName= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ViewModelPropertyName");
            }
        }
```

for the following bindings

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding ViewModelPropertyName}" />
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding PropertyNameWithinObject} />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and assign the class "ViewModel" in datacontext of this page in c# or design, here i declared in c# page,
like

```
this.DataContext = ViewModel;
```